# change title of menuItem

Tags: java

I am having some problems changing the title of my menuitem once created.

i tried this:

```
MenuItem nativeItem = new MenuItem(nativeTitle);
nativeItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if(menuItemEnable.isSelected()){
         nativeItem.setTitle("Enable Native Hook"); //This is not working
      }else{
         nativeItem.setTitle("Disable Native Hook"); //This is not working
      }
   }
});
menu.add(nativeItem);
```

Comment: What type of menu item are you using? `java.awt.MenuItem` does not have a `setTitle()` method. Try using `setLabel()` instead.

Comment: Could you add the whole code? Maybe someone can solve it.

Comment: Worked, i was using java.awt.MenuItem, forgot i was using awt and not swing because i was using swing for something else:D

Comment: i cant accept answer because it is an comment i guess "Gizem" ;D

Answer (score 0):

Thx gla3dr

Use this

setLabel("Hello");